# How can I get a list of phone (iOS) providers programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, core-telephony

Is it possible to access the list of providers on the phone?

I already found a home provider. But it's not clear how to look at other providers.

```
struct InfoProvider {
    let networkOperator: String
    let country: String?
    let mobileCountryCode: String?
    let mobileNetworkCode: String?
}

func getHomeProvider() -> InfoProvider? {
    var homeProvider: InfoProvider? = nil
    let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    if let carrier = networkInfo.subscriberCellularProvider {
        if let carrierName = carrier.carrierName {
            homeProvider = InfoProvider(networkOperator: carrierName,
                                      country: carrier.isoCountryCode,
                                      mobileCountryCode: carrier.mobileCountryCode,
                                      mobileNetworkCode: carrier.mobileNetworkCode)
        }
    }
    return homeProvider
}

func getProviders() -> [InfoProvider] {
    var providers = [InfoProvider]()
    // home provider record
    if let homeProvider = self.getHomeProvider() {
        providers.append(homeProvider)
    }
    /*
     recording of other providers
    */
    return providers
}
```

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: You need to show the code you've written so far.

Comment: Thanks for the help, added code.